# Assign factor for row that meets condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

How do I create an additional column which assigns a factor based on whether the row meets 1 of 3 conditions?

In the example, I want the column to assign a 1 if only an entry for a exists, a 2 if an entry for a and b exists, and a 3 if a row has an entry for a,b and c.

```
before <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,3,2,2,4),
  b = c(NA,2,3,NA,3),
  c = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,5)
)
```

```
after <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,3,2,2,4),
  b = c(NA,2,3,NA,3),
  c = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,5),
  level = c(1,2,2,1,3)
)
```

Comment: What if `a` is missing but `b` and `c` are available?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Such a situation was impossible in my dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.na` and `rowSums` to count how many entry's exists per row.

```
before$level <- rowSums(!is.na(before))
before
#  a  b  c level
#1 1 NA NA     1
#2 3  2 NA     2
#3 2  3 NA     2
#4 2 NA NA     1
#5 4  3  5     3
```